# Unable to create a User Control Module for ASP.NET controls in DNN 8

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

I'm trying to create a User Control Module in DNN 8 to pull in ASP.NET controls that I've already built(a contact form). I made sure the Control Module Name and Control Name match the name of the ascx and ascx.cs files that I created. But when I click Create Module, I get an error "An error occurred when reading the selected module template files." I go to the Event Viewer and see a Host Alert "Processing Template Folder: C:...\DesktopModules\Admin\ModuleCreator\Templates\C#\Module-UserControl". I checked permissions for the DesktopModule folder and for the files in the above path and they all looked ok.

This is my first DNN site using v8. In previous versions, I followed this same process but never got this error. If I had everything set up correctly, the module was created and pulled in my contact form. I'm not sure what's different about version 8 and haven't had any luck on the Google.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up pointing my local instance to the production database and was able to create the module. I then went to the production instance and added it... that shouldn't have worked but I think its related to my hosting provider.